# Trying to find informtion on how to format enyo controls

Tags: enyo

I saw some code that had the controls in a flex box set to go at the end or begging and some where centered.
I tried looking at https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/enyo/enyo-api-reference.html#enyo.ContainedDomBuilder for eny control, then try looking at enyo,contained,Dombbuilder, sice it extends from it.  I also tried to look at https://developer.palm.com/content/api/dev-guide/enyo.html cannot fine any documention on formatting the controls. 
does any body know a good like that would help me?
Ted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the flexible box model - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/

The quick answer is that in your VorHFlexBoxorLayout you can use the properties **pack** and **align** with values like **center**, **start**, etc.